# zlib not available during python 3.7.0 install through pyenv, how can I fix this?

Tags: python-3.x, virtualenv, zlib, pyenv, xcode-command-line-tools

**OS:** MacOS 10.14 Beta

**Goal:** Install Python 3.7.0 Through PYENV

**When trying to install python 3.7.0 through pyenv I get this error, how can I fix this?**

```
    Last 10 log lines:
  File "/private/tmp/python-build.20180704152803.38921/Python-3.7.0/Lib/ensurepip/__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
    sys.exit(ensurepip._main())
  File "/private/tmp/python-build.20180704152803.38921/Python-3.7.0/Lib/ensurepip/__init__.py", line 204, in _main
    default_pip=args.default_pip,
  File "/private/tmp/python-build.20180704152803.38921/Python-3.7.0/Lib/ensurepip/__init__.py", line 117, in _bootstrap
    return _run_pip(args + [p[0] for p in _PROJECTS], additional_paths)
  File "/private/tmp/python-build.20180704152803.38921/Python-3.7.0/Lib/ensurepip/__init__.py", line 27, in _run_pip
    import pip._internal
zipimport.ZipImportError: can't decompress data; zlib not available
make: *** [install] Error 1
```

**Steps Taken To Attempt To Fix:**

**1)** Reinstall XCODE

**2)** Reinstall XCODE Command Line Tools

**3)** Read Similar Errors on Stack Overflow

**Alternate Questions:**

**1)** zlib should come preinstalled, what kind of issue might I be experiencing?

**2)** What is an alternate way to manually install python into a pyenv that would also be recognized by pynev?

Answer (score 2):

Specifically for Python 3.7.0 I did the following with success:

Brew gives some nice instructions when you run info zlib

```
$ brew info zlib
...
For compilers to find zlib you may need to set:
  export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/zlib/lib"
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/zlib/include"
...
```

So given these instructions, I simply cut/paste FTW :)

```
$ export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/zlib/lib"
$ export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/zlib/include"
$ pyenv install 3.7.0   # Succeeded
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. First i tried to install python manually with

```
./configure --prefix /usr/local/var/pyenv/versions/3.5.5/
make
make install
```

Build completed, but i got errors about openssl and zlib , too. Then i tried again with changed build environment:

```
export CPPFLAGS="-I/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include -I$(brew --prefix openssl)/include"
export LDFLAGS="-L/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib -L$(brew --prefix openssl)/lib"
```

Which succeeded.

Finally i ran in the same shell (with both exported variables):

```
pyenv install 3.5.5
```

Which succeeded, too :-)
HTH